# How to convert an already-uploaded Excel file to Google's spreadsheet format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I need to convert Excel files already uploaded to Google Drive into Google's spreadsheet format. What is the best way to do that programmatically?

I've found [this post (#15)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019#c15), but I can't figure out how to use this code. And it seems intended for Excel files not already stored on Drive. Uploading it again would be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot convert a file in-place, and you'll need to re-upload it. Here's a sample showing how to use an XLSX file already in your drive:

```
function convert(xlsxFileId) { 
  var xlsxBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(xlsxFileId).getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: 'Converted Spreadsheet'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, xlsxBlob, {
    convert: true
  });
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But can you explain the `insert` method's usage? Is it the same method as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples)? Why aren't the parameters you used described there?

Comment: Yes, that's the same method. Apps Script orders the parameters slightly differently though, namely:

resource, requiredArgs, mediaData, optionalArgs

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work anymore... The generated file is an empty XLS one of 0 bytes size. I still have the Drive API enabled. But in the script execution log, there is this line:

`[14-05-01 23:55:30:289 CEST] File.getBlob() [0 secondes]`
Obviously the getBlob() method doesn't work anymore. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: ... and it works back again (I didn't change the code nor my Drive contents). Any idea what might have caused the problem?

Answer (score 3):

For those that stumble upon this: This is possible in both Drive API v2 & v3. Python example:

API v2:

```
drive_service_v2.files().copy(body=body, fileId="0n3xrtmjFpuG3V1g3h24tVHM2a33", convert="true").execute()
```

API v3:

```
new_mime_type = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
file_id_of_Excel_file = "0n3xrtmjFpuG3V1g3h24tVHM2a33"
body = {'name': 'New File Name', 'mimeType': new_mime_type}        
drive_service.files().copy(body=body, fileId=file_id_of_Excel_file).execute()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Super helpful for Python, and is exactly what I needed to go forward.

Answer (score 2):

In **Google Driver V3 API**, just need to set `MimeType`.

```
File file = new File();

file.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
```